# Windows Azure cscfg file, presenting enums

Tags: c#, azure, enums, cscfg

I am writing cscfg file. I want to present one of its values to be enum:

```
enum Importance
{
    None,
    Trivial,
    Regular,
    Important,
    Critical
};
```

I cscfg file I have a following Setting:

```
<Setting name="MySettings" value="None">
```

1. Is it a correct way to present enum in cscfg?
2. How do I read this value to actual enum? And how do I validate if the value doesn`t match enum?

For example:

```
<Setting name="MySettings" value="Kuku">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enum.TryParse` for this:

```
var value = valueFromConfigFile;
Importance val;
if (Enum.TryParse(value, true, out val)){
    // OK, go ahead
}
else{
    // enum not recognized
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the value just like you read any other configuration in a string. Then use [Enum.TryParse<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check and convert the string to an enum.